# Laravel Error : ErrorException Missing argument 1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and I am getting ERROR: when I visit admin/profile/:  Missing argument 1 for AdminController::getProfile()

My AdminController code :

```
public function getProfile($id) {
    if(is_null($id)) Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
    $user = User::find($id);
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.profile', array('user' => $user));
}
```

My routes.php :

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

My admin/profile (blade) view :

```
@if(!is_null($user->id)) 
{{ $user->id }} 
@endif
```

How could I fix this? I want when they go to admin/profile without ($id) to redirect to dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a default `null` value to `$id` like this :

```
public function getProfile($id = null) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You told Laravel that your getProfile method has one parameter:

```
public function getProfile($id) {

}
```

If you want to a request to succeed, you have to pass it in your URL:

```
http://appdev.local/admin/profile/1
```

If you want to see it fail (redirect to dashboard), you'll have to add a default value to your function argument:

```
public function getProfile($id = null) { ... }
```

But you better add this value to it anyway, since you can have bots (or even people) trying to access that route without the parameter.

Your view is too generic too, you have to check if your $user is set:

```
@if(isset($user) && !is_null($user->id)) 
    {{ $user->id }} 
@endif
```

As noted in the comments, the line

```
if(is_null($id)) Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
```

Must have a return:

```
if(is_null($id)) return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
```

About sharing the user to your layout, the problem is that your getProfile($id) is already passing a $user to your view, so what you could do is to add this to your __construct():

```
if (Auth::check()) 
{ 
    $user = Auth::getUser(); 
    View::share('loggedUser', $user);
}
```

And in your view:

```
@if(isset($user) && !is_null($user->id)) 
    {{ $user->id }} 
@else
    {{ $loggedUser->id }} 
@endif
```

About the user not found problem, you have many options, this is one:

public function getProfile($id) {

```
if (is_null($id)) 
{
    return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
}

if ($user = User::find($id)) 
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.profile', array('user' => $user));
}
else
{
    return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard')->withMessage('User not found');
}
```

Comment: That works but I am getting this error now : Undefined variable: user when I view the other pages such as admin/dashboard?

Comment: You have to check if $user is available to your view. Just edited to show how.

Comment: Additionally, you might have trouble with the line `if(is_null($id)) Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');`.  I believe it should be returning for it to work properly.  `if(is_null($id)) return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');`

Comment: how do I share the user details to my layout ? do I add this to my __construct ?.  if (Auth::check()){  
  $user = Auth::getUser();
  View::share('user', $user);
 }

Comment: I also having error when the id doesn't exist in the database , how I can solve that?

Comment: Just edited to provide some solutions to your comment questions.

Comment: it worked , how do I add another parameter where /admin/profile/{id}/{action} , can this be done and how?

Comment: Just add it in your method `getProfile($idm,$action)`.